# MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to make a restful controller to upload files. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884711/spring-file-upload-restful-web-service) 
and made this controller:

```
@RestController
public class MaterialController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String name = "test11";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
}
```

and then i used postman to send a pdf:

[image]

But the server crashes with the error:

```
.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Again i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983296/the-current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request-spring-mvc), and added a `bean.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Unfortunately, **it still complains with the same error.**

Comment: Don't know if it's causing your problem, but the screenshot shows that you didn't name the *part*. According to your `handleFileUpload()` method, you need to give the *part* a name/key value of `file`. Without a *part* name, it probably didn't send anything to the server, and "nothing" = "not multipart".

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to make a directory.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Since you annotated class with `@RestController`, you don't need to annotate method with `@ResponseBody`. See javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you are using Postman for multipart request then don't specify a custom Content-Type in Header. So your Header tab in Postman should be empty. Postman will determine form-data boundary. In Body tab of Postman you should select form-data and select file type. You can find related discussion at https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576

Comment: I didn't get you. can you send an image of right request in postman.

Comment: Check the Headers tab just before Body tab in Postman. Your request is correct but there is some entry in Headers as image shared by you shows Headers(1). Remove entry from there.

Answer (score 21):

That happened once to me: I had a perfectly working Postman configuration, but then, without changing anything, even though I didn't inform the `Content-Type` manually on Postman, it stopped working; following the answers to this question, I tried both disabling the header and letting Postman add it automatically, but neither options worked.

I ended up solving it by going to the `Body` tab, change the param type from `File` to `Text`, then back to `File` and then re-selecting the file to send; somehow, this made it work again. Smells like a Postman bug, in that specific case, maybe?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just switched to text then back to selecting a file and viola it's working again.

Comment: this worked for me, that has to be the accepted

Comment: I hat the same issue .. thx :)

Comment: thank you very much for answer. this bug made me crazy, but solution is quite simple

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the problem is request to server is not a multi-part request. Basically you need to modify your client-side form. For  example:

```
<form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's a rest application, currently, there is no html for client side. i use postman

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara, you can still add it in the headers from your rest client.

Answer (score 15):

I was also facing the same issue with `Postman` for `multipart`. I fixed it by doing the following steps:

- Do not select `Content-Type` in the `Headers` section.
- In `Body` tab of `Postman` you should select `form-data` and select `file type`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

In application.properties, please add this:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
```

and in your html form, you need an : `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
For example:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
```

Hope this help!

Comment: 'spring.http.multipart.enabled' is deprecated. Please use 'spring.servlet.multipart.enabled'.

Comment: Are you sure you want to set 'enabled' flag to 'false'?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I **removed:**

> 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

from my **Interceptor**, and everything works.

```
     intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, httpHandler: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (this.authService.isUserLoggedIn() && httpRequest.url.indexOf('login') === -1) {
  const authReq = httpRequest.clone({
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: this.authService.getBasicAuth()
    })
  });
  return httpHandler.handle(authReq);
} else {
  return httpHandler.handle(httpRequest);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the file which you have selected in the request.

For me i was getting the error because the file was not present in the system, as i have imported the request from some other machine.

Comment: I had the exact problem! Every setting was correct - but one thing: The file did not exist (anymore).
Instead of getting a 'file not found' (or something similar) I would always get `Current request is not a multipart request`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **consumes = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}** to your mapping. Full example :

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{idDocument}/attachments", consumes = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
ResponseEntity<String> addAttachmentsToDocumentForm(@PathVariable Long idDocument, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files){
    documentService.addAttachments(idDocument, files);
    return ok("your response");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadFile) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        service.save(uploadFile);

      message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + uploadFile.getOriginalFilename();
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      message = "Could not upload the file: " + uploadFile.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in ARC (advanced rest client) - specify as below to make it work
`Content-Type multipart/form-data`  (this is header name and header value)
this allows you to add form data as key and values 
you can specify you field name now as per your REST specification and select your file to upload from file selector.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing this issue but it was due to the file i was uploading in postman wasn't in the **postman working directory**
Go to Settings -> General and scroll down to location to find it's location folder and put your files to upload there.

See : [Setup Potman working directory](https://go.pstmn.io/docs-working-directory)

Comment: Basically, import the file to postman again

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue with misspelled  enctype="multipart/form-data", i was fix this exception by doing correct  spelling .
Current request is not a multipart request client side error so please check your form.

Answer (score 0):

add required=false with the parameter
@RequestParam(required = false,value = "file") MultipartFile file

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page. Additionally, in my opionen, what you wrote does not answer the question as there is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may be a postman bug.
same thing happend with me when I am trying to upload the file using postman and getting exception `[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request]`.
Try using form-data whille sending request and while selecting key type fisrt choose text and then choose file, do this for 1-2 times and then try.
My problem got solved after this.

Answer (score 0):

I think a clear image can show everything you need
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, reimporting the file in Postman will resolve the problem.