# Test upload endpoint through postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I am trying to upload a file to my server using an endpoint exposed through spring. However when I try to test the api through postman, I get Current request is not a multipart request error. I went through this question [MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013087/multipartexception-current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request) but still couldn't fix this. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UploadController {

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            storageService.store(file);
            files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());

            message = "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "FAIL to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(message);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/getallfiles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getListFiles(Model model) {
        List<String> fileNames = files
                .stream().map(fileName -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                        .fromMethodName(UploadController.class, "getFile", fileName).build().toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fileNames);
    }

    @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
        Resource file = storageService.loadFile(filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(file);
    }
}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
public class StorageService {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private final Path rootLocation = Paths.get("upload-dir");

    public void store(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
        }
    }

    public Resource loadFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Path file = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
            Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
            if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
        }
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(rootLocation.toFile());
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(rootLocation);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize storage!");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see below I am sending file as form Data and no headers are being set

[image]
[image]

Comment: use key's field = file

Comment: also add the tag spring to this question, for larger audience to see this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see below in the image, and add key value as `file`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller expects a request parameter "file":

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

You have to set the key "file" in postman, where the value is your file (last screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your request header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` (as far as I see in postman it is missing)